# Merge 'Specific' file(from dev branch) into master(branch)

Tags: git

My dev branch has several files and commits from all the developers but I am only interested to merge back changes from one specific file

```
File-A 
File-B
File-C
```

I need to merge everything from File-B (at dev branch) to master
Make File-B at master same as File-B at dev-branch, (preserving all the commit logs)

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It sounds like you want to merge the latest version of a specific file in your dev branch, but then you say that cherry-pick "*doesn't pick all changes*", which seems at odds with what you were just asking. Please review your question and make sure that it clearly expresses your situation and desired outcome.

Comment: Yeah, my question was a bit confusing. I need to merge one specific file in master and keep the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the clarification, something is still missing.  But you can perhaps get what you want using `git merge-file`.  Or maybe not.

> I need to merge everything from File-B (at dev branch) to master

(OK so far)

> Make File-B at master same as File-B at dev-branch, (preserving all the commit logs)

This part makes no sense.

First, "merge" doesn't mean "make the same as".

Second, `git log` shows *commits*.  The commits in a repository *are* the history in the repository.  Each commit is a complete snapshot of a source tree.  Commit `19afc3d` may hold 23 files, and subsequent-or-previous commit `b099ca2` may hold 23 files of the same name, 22 of which have the same content.  But they're just two separate commits, each holding 23 files.

Adding a new commit to a repository does just that: adds a new commit, with a new snapshot.

Running `git merge` does something more complex.  Depending on the existing commit graph and options you supply at the time you run `git merge`, it can make a true merge.  It does this by traversing the *commit graph* to find a *merge base commit,* which is the first commit where the two parts of the graph rejoin:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          E--F--G   <-- dev
```

Here, the merge base is commit `B`.  Git can then figure out what we changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-D>
```

and find out what they changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-G>
```

Git then then *combine* these changes, to get both sets of changes.  So if, with respect to commit `B`, we changed `File-B` to add three lines, and *they* changed `File-B` to *remove* an unrelated set of three lines, the total change will be: add our three lines and remove their three lines.

If Git is able to combine all the changes to all the files, Git will then make a new *merge commit*, with two parents instead of one:

```
...--A--B--C--D---H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          E--F--G   <-- dev
```

That is *a merge commit* (merge as an adjective) or *a merge* (merge as a noun), made using, as its snapshot, *all* files from the base `B` as changed by the *combination* of our changes (`B`-to-`D`) and their changes (`B`-to-`G`).

Some of the files in `H` *may* be the same as some of the files in any of `B`, `D`, and `G`, but if so, that's because of the results of combining the two sets of changes.

If you run `git merge-file`, you must supply the base version of the file and both branch-tip versions of the file.  Git will combine the changes into that one file, the way Git normally does with an actual merge.  Git will *not* make a new commit from the result, and if you do, it will not be a *merge commit*, it will just be an ordinary commit:

```
...--A--B--C--D---H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          E--F--G   <-- dev
```

If you literally want the file to be *the same*—i.e., *ignore* any changes we made in commits `C` and `D`, and just take the version of the file from commit `G` directly—you can do that with `git checkout dev -- File-B`.  Again, committing the result will make an ordinary, non-merge commit.

If you want to make a merge commit, doing a proper merge of `File-B` but ignoring their changes to all files *except* that one specific file, that takes a slightly more complicated set of Git commands:

```
git merge --no-commit dev
git checkout master -- [all files except for FileB]
```

(or, equivalently, save the merged version somewhere, check everything out from `master` with `git checkout master -- .`, then put the merged file back in place and `git add FileB`).  Note, however, that recording this *as* a merge commit tells Git that the correct result for doing the complete merge is whatever you just committed.  If you want, later, to merge other changes from `dev`, you will be making this much harder for yourself.

Comment: you suggested several ways to achieve this and helped me to understand my problem. In simplicity, I wanted to create a patch for all the changes in File-B and apple that on top of master. and using last part of your answer. This is what i did: git checkout --patch dev master -- File-B.c, which simply takes the diff and creates a patch of diff. This also avoids the problem you mentioned where preserving git log is not possible. Thanks

Comment: $git checkout master ; $git checkout --patch dev File-B.c

Comment: Using `git checkout --patch` allows you to selectively apply the difference between the current work-tree version and the version extracted from the specified commit (tip of `dev` in this case). If you take all the differences, that's the same as `git checkout dev File-B.c`. In any case the log message is just whatever you supply on the next `git commit`.